# Add nchar field to DateTime in Informix

Tags: sql, informix

I have a `datetime` field that stores times in UTC format.  There's another `nchar` field that stores the time zone difference based on a location.  I'm trying to combine the two for a report so that the time displayed matches the appropriate time zone.

```
time_stamp          |   time_zone
---------------------------------
2015-11-24 21:00:00 |   -0500
2015-11-23 15:00:00 |   -0600
```

Expected output:

```
2015-11-24 16:00:00
2015-11-23 09:00:00
```

I was able to get this to work by using:

```
extend(time_stamp, year to minute) + (CAST(LEFT(time_zone,3) as int)) units hour
```

While this technically works for the current situation, I really don't like using the `CAST` and `LEFT` functions on the time_zone field since it breaks if the value is not negative.  Seems like there's a much better solution, possible something with `TO_CHAR`.  In an informix database, what is the proper way to combine the `dateime` and `nchar` fields so that the output time is correct?  Ideally I would like to output in non 24 hr format (4:00 PM, etc...) but at this point I'm mainly focused on getting the correct time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ideally, your time zone column would be an `INTERVAL HOUR TO MINUTE` type; you'd then simply add the two columns to get the desired result.  Since it is a character type, substringing in some form will be necessary.  Using LEFT is one option; SUBSTRING is another; using the Informix subscripting notation is another.  The CAST isn't crucial; Informix is pretty good about coercing things.

Unless you actually want only hours and minutes in the result (which is a legitimate choice), your EXTEND operation is unnecessary and undesirable; it means your result won't include the seconds value from your data.

Note that some time zones include minutes values.  Newfoundland is on UTC-04:30; India is on UTC+05:30; Nepal is on UTC+05:45.  (See [World Time Zone](http://www.worldtimezone.com/) for more information.)  Getting the minutes accurate is harder because the sign has to be carried through.

As to formatting in AM/PM notation, apart from the question 'why', the answer is to use the TO_CHAR() function and a ghastligram expressing the time format that you want.

- [TO_CHAR()](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSGU8G_12.1.0/com.ibm.sqlt.doc/ids_sqt_129.htm%23ids_sqt_129)
- [GL_DATETIME](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSGU8G_12.1.0/com.ibm.glsug.doc/ids_gug_085.htm)
- [GL_DATE](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSGU8G_12.1.0/com.ibm.glsug.doc/ids_gug_079.htm%23ids_gug_079)

Demonstration:

```
create table zone_char(time_stamp datetime year to second, time_zone nchar(5));
insert into zone_char values('2015-11-24 21:00:00', '-0500');
insert into zone_char values('2015-11-23 15:00:00', '-0600');
insert into zone_char values('2015-11-22 17:19:21', '+0515');
insert into zone_char values('2015-11-21 02:56:31', '-0430');
```

Various ways to select the data:

```
select  extend(time_stamp, year to minute) + LEFT(time_zone,3) units hour,
        time_stamp + LEFT(time_zone,3) units hour,
        time_stamp + time_zone[1,3] units hour,
        time_stamp + time_zone[1,3] units hour + (time_zone[1] || time_zone[4,5]) units minute,
        TO_CHAR(time_stamp + time_zone[1,3] units hour + (time_zone[1] || time_zone[4,5]) units minute,
                '%A %e %B %Y %I.%M.%S %p')
from zone_char;
```

Sample output:

```
2015-11-24 16:00   2015-11-24 16:00:00   2015-11-24 16:00:00   2015-11-24   16:00:00   Tuesday 24 November 2015 04.00.00 PM
2015-11-23 09:00   2015-11-23 09:00:00   2015-11-23 09:00:00   2015-11-23   09:00:00   Monday 23 November 2015 09.00.00 AM
2015-11-22 22:19   2015-11-22 22:19:21   2015-11-22 22:19:21   2015-11-22   22:34:21   Sunday 22 November 2015 10.34.21 PM
2015-11-20 22:56   2015-11-20 22:56:31   2015-11-20 22:56:31   2015-11-20   22:26:31   Friday 20 November 2015 10.26.31 PM
```

And note how much easier it is when the time zone is represented as an INTERVAL HOUR TO MINUTE:

```
alter table zone_char add hhmm interval hour to minute;
update zone_char set hhmm = time_zone[1,3] || ':' || time_zone[4,5];
```

SELECT:

```
select  time_stamp, hhmm, extend(time_stamp + hhmm, year to minute),
        time_stamp + hhmm,
        TO_CHAR(time_stamp + hhmm, '%A %e %B %Y %I.%M.%S %p')
from zone_char;
```

Result:

```
2015-11-24 21:00:00   -5:00   2015-11-24 16:00   2015-11-24 16:00:00   Tuesday 24 November 2015 04.00.00 PM
2015-11-23 15:00:00   -6:00   2015-11-23 09:00   2015-11-23 09:00:00   Monday 23 November 2015 09.00.00 AM
2015-11-22 17:19:21    5:15   2015-11-22 22:34   2015-11-22 22:34:21   Sunday 22 November 2015 10.34.21 PM
2015-11-21 02:56:31   -4:30   2015-11-20 22:26   2015-11-20 22:26:31   Friday 20 November 2015 10.26.31 PM
```